# CoMarshalInterface() - any way to determine the maximum byte length of result beforehand?

Tags: serialization, com, ipc, messaging

I'm working on a project in which two processes communicate via a TCP-based message bus. For efficiency, I'm considering prepending each message with the byte length of the message.

Some messages however convey information about COM objects; namely, process A calls CoMarshalInterface() and submits the resulting bytes to Process B for deserialization.

In order to determine the byte length of my messages without actually serializing them yet, I'm trying to figure out whether there is any way of knowing the specific, or at least maximum size of bytes that CoMarshalInterface() would yield, without actually having to call that method yet (at least not at this point in code).

Would anybody know if there's any way?
I haven't noticed any big variations in data length for the objects I have tested this with, but I'm not quite sure how CoMarshalInterface works internally. Does it depend on some mechanism implemented by each COM object individually, hence completely unknown size, or is it safe to assume it would never generate more than XYZ bytes of serialized information?

Thanks!

Comment: You are probably looking for [`CoGetMarshalSizeMax`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms692640.aspx)

Comment: Wow, I only had low hopes such a function would actually exist .. amazing. Thanks a lot!!